# XMLReadFile mixed the header proprties

Tags: c, xml

I created an XGMML document (*doc a*), and set the Header properties as I wished (and needed to), and I checked on notepad++ that I got the desired format. 
when trying to open it with XMLReadFile, and saving the document under other name (*doc b*), the Header properties mixed up.

I think it happens on opening because when I opened *doc a* (the good file) on chrome the Header was mixed exactly in the same way it was on *doc b*. so I think chrome and XMLReadFile open the XGMML document in the same way (mixing the Header up), and on saving nothing bad happens.

more importantly, I don't know of other function that opens the XGMML document and doesn't change the Header - it is really important that the Header or any other field won't be changed (I tried to use XMLParseFile but it seems to cause the same problem).

do you know why it happens?
and do you know of a function that opens XGMML document and doesn't mix the Header (or any other field) up?

Comment: Could you provide snippets of the correct and incorrect documents to exemplify what is mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you refer to attributes as properties: An XML element's attributes do not have a significant order by definition. Please see the standard [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags).